# Perl: Passing by reference does not modify the hash

Tags: perl

My understanding was that in Perl we pass hashes to functions by reference

Consider the following example, where we modify the hash in the modifyHash function

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

my %hash;

$hash{"A"} = "1";
$hash{"B"} = "2";


print (keys %hash);
print "\n";

modifyHash(\%hash);

print (keys %hash);
print "\n";

sub modifyHash {
    my $hashRef = @_[0];
    my %myHash = %$hashRef;
    $myHash{"C"} = "3";
    print (keys %myHash);
    print "\n";
}
```

The output of this script is:

```
AB
ABC
AB
```

I would have expected it to be:

```
AB
ABC
ABC
```

...as we pass the hash by reference.

What concept am I missing here about passing hashes to functions?

Comment: Can't explain why someone downvoted other than downvotes happen for many reasons, some irrational.  Anyway, this action: `my %myHash = %$hashRef;` constitutes "pass by value" or "copy by value".  There is no lingering binding between `%myHash` and `$hashRef`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because when you do `my %myHash = %$hashRef;`, you're taking a copy of the dereferenced `$hashref` and putting it into `%myHash` which is the same thing as `my %myHash = %hash;`, so you're not working on the referenced hash at all.

To work on the hash specified by the reference, try this...

```
sub modifyHash {
    my $hashRef = $_[0];
    $hashRef->{"C"} = "3";
    print (keys %$hashRef);
    print "\n";
}
```

As pointed out by ThisSuitIsBlackNot in the comments below, `@_[0]` is better written as `$_[0]`. You should always be using `use strict;` and `use warnings;`, as this would have been caught. Because you're sending in a reference, you could also have used `my $hashRef = shift;`.

Comment: `my $hashRef = @_[0];` better written as `my $hashRef = $_[0];` (which the OP would know if they used warnings)

Comment: Totally agreed... either that or `shift`. I just copy/pasted for the example. I'll fix it for other readers in the future. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the assignment:

```
my %myHash = %$hashRef;
```

This is akin to saying:

```
$x = 5;
$y = $x;
```

You're not setting $y to reference the same spot in memory, you're just giving the value of $x to $y.  In your example, you're creating a new hash (%myHash) and giving it the value of the hash stored at $hashRef.  Any future changes are to the new hash, not the original.

If you want to manipulate the original, you should do something like:

```
${$hashRef}{"C"} = "3";
```

or

```
$hashRef->{"D"} = 4;
```

There might be a more elegant way of doing it, but as far as I know you want to work with the hash reference.